# pass parent object itself as props to children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am using rails with react with no flux.

I realise I am defining too many functions in my parent component `jsx` file so I wanted to refactor it and define the functions in another file.

```
# application.js
//= require_self
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
window.myApp = {}

# custom.js
myApp.sayLol = function(parentComponent) {
  alert("LOL");
  parentComponent.setState({something: 'something'});
}

# parent_component.js.jsx
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
  // sayLol: function(){
  //   alert("LOL");
  //   this.setState({something: 'something'});
  // },
  render: function(){
    // return (<ChildComponent sayLol={this.sayLol} />);
    return (<ChildComponent parentComponent={this} />);
  }
})

# child_component.js.jsx
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    myApp.sayLol(this.props.parentComponent);
  },
  render: function(){
    return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}>say LOL</div>)
  }
})
```

So what I have done is define the functions, namely `sayLol()`, that the components are going to call in a separate `custom.js` file.

The tutorial way was to define the functions inside the parent component as local function which is usually passed to the child as props, as shown as comments in `parent_component.js.jsx`.

I am also passing the parent object so that i can use the decoupled function defined in `custom.js` to do something like changing the state of the parent object from WITHIN the child component.

It is currently working on my application but I am not sure if passing the parent object itself as a whole is a good thing. Love to hear any advices :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nah. Passing the whole parent object is probably not what want. This is because that the child object has to have too much knowledge about the internals of the parent. This ultimately creates extra hard to test spaghetti code.

Instead pass in specific callbacks as props. Those callbacks don't necessarily need to be methods from the parent component, but that often makes them easier to test.

If you have a ton of callbacks it might make sense to group them in a single object that gets passed as a prop, but most apps just pass single callbacks explicitly.